# Eclipse git: how to push your code to remote git repository in a debian VPS

Tags: eclipse, git, debian, vps

I have a debian VPS containing a git repository.

From the git repository I successfully created a new project in eclpise.

The url for clone: git://myWebsite.com/myRepository.git

So I started coding in my local machine and then I wanted to commit and push changes to the repository in the VPS, but it didn't work: git://myWebsite.com/myRepository.git access denied.

This is what I expected, because it's logic that somewhere you have to authenticate to your VPS.

I have a SSH access to my VPS (with a RSA key and with a simple login authenitcation). The question is: how and where do I have to configure authentication?

Fake username: pippo

Fake password: oppip

Comment: So you´ve got permissions on this Repo with your account? You´ve set up at least your mailadress on local git and entered/enabled RSA key for authentification?

Comment: @LenglBoy no, I didn't perform any authentatication. If you read my question, I'm asking how to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

`git://` protocol is for cloning but not for pushing. You need to change URL to an `ssh://` URL:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://pippo@myWebsite.com/path/to/myRepository.git
```

or

```
git remote set-url origin pippo@myWebsite.com:relative/path/myRepository.git
```